# unable to parse queue in pm2

Tags: laravel, jobs

I want to add these jobs in server but have error(pm2) :

```
 apps:
  - name: laravel-queue-worker
    script:php /var/www/html/backendcodes/artisan
    exec_mode: fork
    interpreter: php
    instances: 1
    args:
      - queue:work
      - --queue=sendSms,sendNotification,sendEmail
      - --tries=3
      - --sleep=3
```

when I run

> pm2 start laravel-queue-worker.yml

it returns :

```
 [PM2][ERROR] File laravel-queue-worker.yml malformated
    { [Error: Unable to parse.]
      message: 'Unable to parse.',
      parsedLine: 3,
  snippet: 'script:php /var/www/html/raffle-backend-master/artisan' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this .yaml, you can use a lint online for check the syntax, like [this](http://www.yamllint.com/).
The problem was here -> `script:php/var/www/html/backendcodes/artisan`
You need to insert a space after script:.

```
apps: 
  - 
    args: 
      - "queue:work"
      - "--queue=sendSms,sendNotification,sendEmail"
      - "--tries=3"
      - "--sleep=3"
    exec_mode: fork
    instances: 1
    interpreter: php
    name: laravel-queue-worker
    script: "php /var/www/html/backendcodes/artisan"
```